# Get index of selected CollectionView item from underlying ObservableCollection source

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, collectionview, collectionviewsource

I have a CollectionView that is bound to the ListView ItemsSource property.

```
<ListView x:Name="ExampleView" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionView}" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">...</ListView>
```

Is it possible to get the index of an item from the CollectionViewSource?

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ObservableCollection);
```

Below I have illustrated the problem.

When item C from the CollectionView is selected, I want to get an index value of 2 and not 0. Is this possible?
[image]

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. It assumes, as your code suggests, that the view you're filtering is the default view for this `ObservableCollection`.

```
var vw = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyObservableCollection);

int index = MyObservableCollection.IndexOf(vw.CurrentItem);
```

Of course you could also bind `ListBox.SelectedItem` to a `SelectedItem` property on your viewmodel, and take the index of that also.

Comment: I bound an int property to ListBox.SelectedItem, the problem is that it gives me the same value as the CollectionView. Your solution is certainly an option, but wouldn't that be inherently slow if I have many items, as it has to iterate through all items to find the right one?

Comment: @HaloMediaz That's true. If they're sorted you could search efficiently, but that's a big "if", of course. Do the items change often?

Comment: No. I call refresh on the CollectionView when a textbox's text changes, which occurs only when the user searches via that textbox. I only need to get the item, when the user selects it from the search box. I recorded my screen of what I'm talking about: https://imgur.com/ctgPIQv

Comment: *If* it turns out to be an issue (don't borrow trouble), you could give the list item class an index property. Assign it when you add it to the collection. For that UI, where you populate and then discard them all, that seems appropriate. But again, wait to see the problem before you complicate anything to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem to be an issue as of right now :)